# Rewrite subdomain to subdomain/folder in vhost situation

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, subdomain, url-rewriting, vhosts

I'm trying to rewrite `abc.example.com/path` to `abc.example.com/index.php/abc/path` using the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(abc)\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/abc/$1 [L]
```

The situation is:

```
domain    www.example.com
vhost     www
subdomain abc.example.com
vhost     abc
```

I don't want `index.php/abc/` to be shown in the URL.

Does anybody have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With the following code everything you type after the domain will be appended to /index.php/abc

```
abc.domain.com/URL      -> abc.domain.com/index.php/abc/URL
abc.domain.com/URL/     -> abc.domain.com/index.php/abc/URL/
abc.domain.com/URL/URL  -> abc.domain.com/index.php/abc/URL/URL
abc.domain.com/URL/URL/ -> abc.domain.com/index.php/abc/URL/URL/
```

Rewrite code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(abc).domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/%1$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but no...

the situation is:
abc.domain.com   -> abc.domain.com/index.php/abc ( or www.domain.com/index.php/abc )
to be more complete:
abc.domain.com/features   -> abc.domain.com/index.php/abc/features ( or www.domain.com/index.php/abc/features )
and
abc.domain.com/features/feature   -> abc.domain.com/index.php/abc/features/feature ( or www.domain.com/index.php/abc/features/feature )

Comment: Adjusted my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index.php/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```